# HTML & Javascript - Displaying buttons for only specific objects

Tags: javascript, html, object, button, drop-down-menu

So I'm creating an online store program in HTML and Javascript where there is a dropdown menu of different departments and when the user selects a specific department, an inventory for that department displays in text on HTML which lists various items.

Everything seems to work fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I would insert buttons for only specific keys for the objects given in the javascript file. Like for example, I want the keys to only display for each line in the department's inventory that ends with a price. I'm not sure how to do that on HTML as I can't really make a for loop or anything.

Right now my HTML file basically just shows this below without the buttons. But here's an example of where I want the buttons to go on my browser:

Mike's Computers

Laptops

iMac $2000 [BUTTON]

Dell $600 [BUTTON]

Computers

Windows PC $1300 [BUTTON]

The buttons don't need any functionaity right now, I'm just struggling to figure out how I would iterate through all the lines and place buttons only in certain spots. I would really appreciate any help. If there are any resources for this specific problem, I'd also be happy to take a look at them.

store.js:

```
let electronics = {
    store: "Mike's Computers",
    inventory: {
        "Laptops": {
            0: {
                brand: "iMac",
                cost: 2000
            },
            1: { 
                brand: "Dell",
                cost: 600
            }
        },
        "Computers": {
            2: {
                brand: "Windows PC",
                cost: 1300
            }
        }
    }
};

function showOptions(){
    let userPicked = document.getElementById("list").value;
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    if(userPicked == 'one'){
        var newContent = (electronics.store);
        newContent += '<br>';       
        Object.keys(electronics.inventory).forEach(key => {
           newContent += '<br>';
           newContent += key;
           newContent += '<br>';
           var items = Object.values(electronics.inventory[key]);
           items.forEach(item => {
              newContent += `&nbsp;  ${item.brand}  $${item.cost}`;
              newContent += '<br>';
           });
        });
        div.innerHTML = newContent;
    }else{
        alert("You must select a store.");
    }
}
```

store.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Welcome</h1></div><br />
    <div class="dropdown">
        <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
            <option value="none">Pick store</option>
            <option value="one">Electronics</option> 
        </select>
        <input type=button value="Select" onclick="showOptions()" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div"></div>
        <script src="store.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the button markup in the inner loop. I will also encourage you not use `<br>` element.

Try the following way:

```js
let electronics = {
  store: "Mike's Computers",
  inventory: {
    "Laptops": {
      0: {
        brand: "iMac",
        cost: 2000
      },
      1: { 
        brand: "Dell",
        cost: 600
      }
    },
    "Computers": {
        2: {
          brand: "Windows PC",
          cost: 1300
        }
    }
  }
};

function showOptions(el){
    let userPicked = el.value;
    var div = document.getElementById("div");
    if(userPicked != 'none'){
        var newContent = (electronics.store);
        newContent += '<div>';       
        Object.keys(electronics.inventory).forEach(key => {
           newContent += key;
           newContent += '<div>';
           var items = Object.values(electronics.inventory[key]);
           items.forEach(item => {
              newContent += '<div>';
              newContent += `&nbsp; <span class="brand"> ${item.brand} </span>  <span class="price">$${item.cost}</span>`;
              newContent += `<input type=button value="Product" onclick="product(this)"/>`
              newContent += '</div>';
           });
           newContent += '</div>';
        });
        newContent += '</div>';
        div.innerHTML = newContent;
    }else{
        alert("You must select a store.");
    }
}

function product(product){
  console.clear();
  console.log(product.closest('div').textContent.trim())
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Welcome</h1></div><br />
    <div class="dropdown">
        <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target" onchange="showOptions(this)">
            <option value="none">Select a restaurant</option>
            <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option> 
        </select>
        <input type=button value="Select" onclick="showMenuIntro()" />
        </form>
        
    </div>
    <div id="div"></div>
        <script src="store.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jstl in your html code
jstl can make you can use for tag

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${list}" begin=0 end=5 step=1 varStatus="status">
    count: ${status.count}
    name : ${item.name}
    age : ${item.age}
    address : ${item.addr}
</c:forEach>
```

before you use jstl you have to import tag library

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
let electronics = {
  store: "Mike's Computers",
  inventory: {
    "Laptops": {
      0: {
        brand: "iMac",
        cost: 2000
      },
      1: {
        brand: "Dell",
        cost: 600
      }
    },
    "Computers": {
      2: {
        brand: "Windows PC",
        cost: 1300
      }
    }
  }
};

function showOptions() {
  let userPicked = document.getElementById("list").value;
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (userPicked == 'one') {
    var newContent = (electronics.store);
    newContent += '<br>';
    Object.keys(electronics.inventory).forEach(key => {
      newContent += '<br>';
      newContent += key;
      newContent += '<br>';
      var items = Object.values(electronics.inventory[key]);
      items.forEach(item => {
        newContent += `&nbsp;  ${item.brand}  $${item.cost}`;
        newContent += `<button onclick="showSelectedProduct('${key}','${item.brand}','${item.cost}')">Show Selected Product</button>`;
        newContent += '<br>';
      });
    });
    div.innerHTML = newContent;
  } else {
    alert("You must select a store.");
  }
}

function showSelectedProduct(cat, brand, price)
{
  alert(cat + "-" +brand + "-"+ price)
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
  </div><br />
  <div class="dropdown">
    <form>
      <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
        <option value="none">Pick store</option>
        <option value="one">Electronics</option>
      </select>
      <input type=button value="Select" onclick="showOptions()" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="div"></div>
</body>

</html>
```